# SharePoint workflow "now" function

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, json

I am trying to create a workflow that will automatically update a field based on `creation date +3 days;3-5 days; 5> days.`

How can I tell the flow to calculate if 3; 3-5; 5> days have passed since the ticket was created?

I was thinking about adding a Condition where the "Created" column compares [Today] and if the difference is higher than 3 days for eg. to populate a column in a List

Is there any expression that I can use so, for e.g
If 3 days have passed the flow automatically updates a specific column with "3 days since the thicket was logged".

I was thinking about the utcNow() function but I`m not really sure how to make to flow calculate +3 days since the ticket was created.

Answer (score 0):

At my job, we use retention policies which are scheduled to evaluate timers once a day. If you enable a retention policy on your list, you can use criteria to say "Kick off this workflow x days after creation/modified" or you can even use it to run the workflow once a day and then just have the logic in your workflow setup so that you can check the item to see if it matches any custom criteria you have set up (e.g., status is closed).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/retention-policies
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the Add Time to Date action.

[image]